# Horizontally aligning elements of different heights and unknown widths using css

Tags: html, css

Consider the following [image]

```html
<span class="title">
  <h1>This is the title</h1>
  <input type="button" class="btn"></input>
</span>
```

I want the `<span>` to be 100% in width. The button just has an icon and the button size is 40 x 40. Now the width and height of the button is known and the width and height of `<h1>` is unknown.
I want the `<h1>` and `<input>` to be vertically aligned in middle of `<span>` and horizontally aligned as in the image. I want the `<h1>` center-aligned in the `<span>` and the `<input>` should be to the right. How can I achieve this with CSS?

Comment: Check over your post, I feel like there are a few key words missing.

Answer (score 2):

**Use below code and modify as per your needs.**

```css
div{display:table;width:100%;border:1px solid;}
span{display:table-cell;height:150px;text-align:center;vertical-align:middle;}
.btn{float:right;}
h1{margin:0;}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="title">
    <input type="button" class="btn"></input>
    <h1>This is the title</h1>
  </span>
</div>
```